# Extracting nested monadic result: m (m a) -> m a

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative

I have a function

```
parseArgs :: [String] -> StdGen -> IO ()
```

which selects the function to run. The main looks like

```
main = parseArgs <$> getArgs <*> getStdGen >>= id
```

The problem I have, `parseArgs <$> getArgs <*> getStdGen` is of type `IO (IO ())`, which I extract using `(>>= id)` which is of type `Monad m => m (m b) -> m b`. Is there a way to avoid requiring the "extraction" of the value while having just a single line function?

Comment: Don't you already have a single line function ?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to avoid the extraction, which is done by the `(>>= id)` function.

Comment: May I ask why you want to avoid using `(>>= id)`? It seems the best way if you're using a `Monad m => m (m a) -> m a` constraint, because some other solutions might have `(Applicative m, Monad m)` etc, which makes less sense in the context.

Comment: @AJFarmar I wasn't avoiding particularly `(>>= id)`, but any requirement to do the extraction whatsoever. Seems like that is impossible. Not that it really matters, because all this was purely for learning purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be with `join`:

```
main = join $ parseArgs <$> getArgs <*> getStdGen
```

Personally, I would prefer the form

```
main = join $ liftM2 parseArgs getArgs getStdGen
```

where

```
join   :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> r) -> m a -> m b -> m r
```

Or just use a do

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    gen  <- getStdGen
    parseArgs args gen
```

Comment: Well, apparently `join` is exactly the same I was doing. It still doesn't answer the question though. Is it possible or not?

Comment: @Seig The question was "Is there a way to avoid requiring the 'extraction' (`>>= id`) of the value while having just a single line function?"  The answer to that question is yes, using `join`.  Are you wanting an existing combinator that would have the type `Monad m => (a -> b -> m r) -> m a -> m b -> m r`?  A quick search on Hoogle doesn't come up with anything, I'd say that `join` would be the idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: Well, that fulfills it.

Comment: `main = join $ liftM2 parseArgs getArgs getStdGen` how can you prefer this?!?

Comment: @alternative It only takes 1 import, and uses fewer operators and symbols.  Really, I'd prefer do notation, since it's abundantly obvious what's happening, but if given the choice between the first two, I'd stick with the entirely monadic one, not the monadic and applicative one.  But it's all opinion, I certainly don't regard the first as "wrong" in any way.

Answer (score 3):

You can define an operator for this:

```
infixl 4 <&>

(<&>) :: Monad m => m (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
f <&> x = f >>= (x >>=)
```

If you have a function of type

```
f :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> ... -> an -> m b) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> ... -> m an -> m b
```

then you can write

```
fx :: Monad m => m b
fx = f <$> x1 <*> x2 <*> ... <&> xn
```

where each `xi` has type `m ai`.

In your case it would be simply

```
parseArgs <$> getArgs <&> getStdGen
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pair up the arguments and put them through a single bind:

```
main = uncurry parseArgs =<< (,) <$> getArgs <*> getStdGen
```

This avoids the extraction from nested IO. Admittedly it's no shorter but I find it easier to think about.

It fits a general pattern of `doTheWork =<< getAllTheInputs` which might be the way you'd end up arranging things anyway, if the code was more complicated.