# Multi-argument monadic bind

Tags: haskell, monads

Is there a `>>=` for functions of two arguments? Something like

```
bind2 :: m a -> m b -> (a -> b -> m c) -> m c
```

Comment: `Control.Monad.liftM2` -- with arguments in a different (& usually more convenient) order

Comment: @luqui: `liftM2` takes a function of type `a -> b -> c`, whereas this hypothetical `bind2` takes a function of type `a -> b -> m c`.

Comment: Oops you're right, sloppy reading.  No there isn't, unfortunately.  You can use `join (liftM2 op x y)`.

Comment: @luqui +1 for `join` and `liftM2`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine monads that take multiple arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115472/combine-monads-that-take-multiple-arguments)

Comment: It's a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134349/extracting-nested-monadic-result-m-m-a-m-a). But the question is stated clearer here.

Comment: @user3237465 However the answer to the other question is much more complete.

Comment: I'm new to SO so I don't know how the duplicate system works, but it is possible to merge two questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what clever combinators you could use to build this out of the standard library, but at the risk of stating the obvious it is pretty easy to implement yourself:

```
bind2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
bind2 f ma mb = do
  a <- ma
  b <- mb
  f a b

> bind2 (\a b -> [a,b]) [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
[1,4,1,5,1,6,2,4,2,5,2,6,3,4,3,5,3,6]
```

Comment: luqui's comment seems to give a sensible combo.